# Problems with a Choropleth map

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

Im trying to obtain a Choropleth map in R using map and ggplot2 packages. Im interesting in just represent specifics countries and specific values for them. My data is the following:

```
GEO<-c("ES","GB","FR","DE","DK","AT","PT")
Value<-c(0.2560,0.023,0.0120,0.158,0.0025,0.158,0.2)
countries=c("Spain","Great Britain","France","German","Denmark","Austria","UK")
datar<-data.frame(GEO,Value,countries)
```

datar$GEO corresponds to the ISO 2 code name for countries.

I obtain a Choropleth map using this script:

```
mapa<-fortify(map(regions=datar$countries,col="grey20",fill=TRUE,plot=FALSE))

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=mapa, map=mapa,
                aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=region),
                fill="white", color="black")
gg<- gg +geom_map(data=datar, map=mapa,
              aes(map_id=countries,fill=Value),color="blue",size=0.25)
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg
```

Here the map:
 [image]

First problem is that Grate Britain is not in the picture. I tried to change the nomenclature to "UK". It is worst since it represents Namibia not England.. I try to search for the correct name of UK but didn't find anything! Someone knows? datar$GEO does not produce even a plot [Error en seq_len(nrow(data) - 1) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer]

Second. I would like to create a color scale in red from 0 to 0.5. Where and how I should do it?

And last, How can I remove the lat and long numbers, along with the background lines and square.

Thanks!

Comment: Where does the `map()` function come from? You should include external packages used

Comment: map() comes from maps package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is in fact a simple fix.
data.frame() by default changes a character vector into a factor, which can confuse code in many ways. You probably see warnings about that:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iexp, value = "UK$)|(^UK:") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

So indeed you need to use "UK" in stead of "Great Britain" or "United Kingdom", but the NAmibia can be avoided by using

```
datar <- data.frame(GEO,Value,countries, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

This error with factors only pops up for the UK because of the hackish fix for "uk" vs "ukraine". I'll fix that in the next release (3.2) of maps.

Answer (score 1):

`geom_map()` is always a bit of pain to deal with, I learned that.

The correct code for Great Britain is indeed `UK`, but, contrary to the other countries you search for, it has sub-regions. Searching for just `UK` will return `NA` and this (weirdly) will return `NAmibia`.
The solution is to search for `UK:`.

Btw, you can use `map_data()` instead of `fortify(map(..))`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)

datar <- data.frame(GEO = c("ES","UK","FR","DE","DK","AT","PT"), 
                    Value = c(0.2560,0.023,0.0120,0.158,0.0025,0.158,0.2),
                    search_countries = factor(c("Spain","UK:","France","Germany","Denmark","Austria", "Portugal")),
                    countries = c("Spain","UK","France","Germany","Denmark","Austria", "Portugal")
)

mapa <- map_data('world', region = datar$search_countries)
```

We still need the `countries` column as they were originally, to join `mapa` and `datar`.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_map(data = mapa, map = mapa, aes(x = long, y = lat,map_id = region)) +
  geom_map(data = datar, map = mapa, aes(fill = Value, map_id = countries), color ='black', size = .25) +
  coord_map() 
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: x, y
```

[image]

This is where the `geom_map` weirdness comes out. but you probably already know that, as you correctly plotted two `geom_map` and the weirdness about the required but warning `x` & `y` aesthetics.

Last thing to do is to fix the fill scale, and remove the theme's elements that aren't needed (You could achieve the same result using `theme_void()`)

```
last_plot() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'white', high = 'red', limits = c(0, .5)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = 'black', fill = 'white'),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: As a comment about needing the colon "UK:" : this in fact stems from the fact that "uk" by itself would also fit "ukrain" (which didn't exist >20 years ago when it was decided to use "uk" in stead of "Great Britain". To stay compatible, maps 3.x now turns plain "uk" into an ugly regular expression that apparently confuses geom_map(), resulting in "NA".